# Retrieve an image stored in a database to display it on an ASP.Net MVC website?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, image, asp.net-mvc-3, filestream

I've a database, which contains some pictures in a varbinary(Max) Filestream field in a database.

I've to display it on a website, with information of the current row of the table.

What is the best way to display in an ASP.NET MVC 3 website an image stored in the database?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Download and Upload images from SQL Server via ASP.Net MVC](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/) ?

Sorry to be short, but easier than copy/pasting...